# Finding 3rd Lowest Value Without Sort

Tags: python, sorting

So I'm tasked with finding the third lowest value of a given list. My code looks like

```
def findMinIndex(L, startIndex):
    minIndex = startIndex
    currIndex = minIndex + 1
    while currIndex < len(L):
        if L[currIndex] < L[minIndex]:
            minIndex = currIndex
            currIndex = currIndex + 1
    return minIndex

def thirdSmallest(L):
    i = 0
    while i < len(L): 
        minIndex = findMinIndex(L, i)
        L[i], L[minIndex] = L[minIndex], L[i]
        i = i + 1
    print(L[2])


thirdSmallest([1, 99, 7, -3, 3, 10, 12])
```

The list I have for L should print 3 as the 3rd lowest value, but anaconda is taking an incredibly long time to return anything to me. I was given a hint that I should modify

```
while i < len(L):
```

or my print function. But I dont see what I should do. Any advice?

Comment: I'm guessing you can't just use [`heapq.nsmallest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest)...

Comment: No, has to be without any of the built in search functions or the ones in a library.

Comment: @mgilson if the name is anyway related to the concept, then i believe this it arranges the list in a minheap and returns the first n numbers from the head of the tree, which is not what Poster wants, I believe, as he/she does not want to use sorting algorithm, which will make the runtime `O(nlogn)`. I think he/she is after a `O(n)` algorithm.

Comment: @anu, `nsmallest` is `O(n*Log(m))` where `m` is the constant `3` in this case - so `O(n)`

Comment: @CabooseMSG you know know how to find the smallest number in the list right ? Why not run the function to find the smallest number in the list thrice, each time removing the smallest number out of the list.

Comment: @anu -- You can heapify a list in roughly [linear (O(N)) time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.heapify)  ... If you do that and then do 3 pops, you're left with an `O(N) + O(logN)` algorithm which most people just report as O(N) since that is the leading factor.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy Oh ok. I stand corrected then and the name does not actually do justice to what it's doing. Because I thought the best algorithm  do to create a heap was `O(nlogn)`

Comment: I think writing your own sort might be faster than running this thrice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you want to do, but I've find one error, leading to potential infinite loop:

```
def findMinIndex(L, startIndex):
    minIndex = startIndex
    currIndex = minIndex + 1
    while currIndex < len(L):
        if L[currIndex] < L[minIndex]:
            minIndex = currIndex
        currIndex = currIndex + 1  # Error corrected here
    return minIndex
```

Comment: Cant believe I was fooled by dumb indentation, thought it was something else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This loop will run forever if the `if` condition is false

```
while currIndex < len(L):
    if L[currIndex] < L[minIndex]:
        minIndex = currIndex
        currIndex = currIndex + 1
```

Comment: Wow, yea, thats it, I thought it was something inherently more complex. Just indentation though. Thank you!